# Ant retrieve doesn't include specific quickactionlistitem in layout metadata

Tags: metadata, ant, migration-tool

We are using a simple ant script to retrieve certain types of metadata in our org, including various page layouts. On one such layout, we have some quickactions.

We've noticed that when using the script, it would refresh everything normally, but for some reason leave out the Case.Email quickaction from one specific Case layout. As in, this piece of xml:

```
    <quickActionListItems>
        <quickActionName>Case.Email</quickActionName>
    </quickActionListItems>
```

would simply not be in the file any more. This does not happen when refreshing the layout file using Mavensmate.

The ant script we are using only contains one action:

```
<sf:retrieve username="${sf.usernameDev}" password="${sf.passwordDev}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="src/" unpackaged="src/package.xml" unzip="true" />
```

and our package.xml is the one generated by Mavensmate (which we know is correct).

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Is the quickAction retrieved at all? Or is the quick action also missing? Is it part of a pacakge? What about the Case layout?

Comment: @mkorman The quickaction also seems to be missing, and nothing is part of a package. In our package.xml quickactions are retrieved using `<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>`

Comment: I assume that the fact that the QA is missing is what it makes it missing from your layout. Can you try to retrieve it by name? We retrieve all our custom actions by name (yes, each and every single one of them). Our package.xml looks like this: `<types>
        <members>ActionNameHere</members>
        <members>AnotherActionNameHere</members>
        <name>QuickAction</name>
    </types>`  so it's not too different from yours.

Comment: @mkorman I've added them by name as you suggested and now the tool gives me an error saying `Entity of type 'QuickAction' named 'Case.Email' cannot be found`

Comment: You're probably referencing it using the wrong name. What I found is that if the action is Global (ie: it shows under Setup > Create > Global Actions > Global Actions), you need to use the name exactly as shown in the 'Name' column; if the action is object-specific (ie: Build > Customize > Cases > Buttons, Links and Actions), then you need to use `<object>.<name>` (name as displayed in the 'Name' column). For instance `Contact.Call`. Oddly enough it looks like that's what you're doing.

Comment: @mkorman According to a different SE post it seems like there is a bug in the metadata api regarding standard quickactions. It involves the retrieve not including the object in the QA name. I tested by just adding a QA called 'Email'. This gives a similar error as before, but fixes my layout at the same time. Very strange, but at least I can set up some sort of workaround now.

Comment: Glad we could help :)